# Erro ao execultar Composer install

Tags: laravel-5, composer, artisan

Estou clonando um repositório do GitHub [GitScrum](https://github.com/renatomarinho/GitScrum) e quando vou executar o comando `Composer Install`, ele me retorna o seguinte erro:

> C:\www\GitScrum>composer install
>
> [32mLoading composer repositories with package information[39m
>   [32mInstalling dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file[39m
>   [37;41mYour requirements could not be resolved to an installable set
>   of packages.[39;49m
>
> Problem 1
>       - Installation request for guzzle/guzzle v3.8.1 -> satisfiable by guzzle/guzzle[v3.8.1].
>       - guzzle/guzzle v3.8.1 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.   Problem 2
>       - Installation request for intervention/image 2.3.8 -> satisfiable by intervention/image[2.3.8].
>       - intervention/image 2.3.8 requires ext-fileinfo * -> the requested PHP extension fileinfo is missing from your system.
>   Problem 3
>       - Installation request for knplabs/github-api 1.7.1 -> satisfiable by knplabs/github-api[1.7.1].
>       - knplabs/github-api 1.7.1 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.   Problem 4
>       - knplabs/github-api 1.7.1 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
>       - graham-campbell/github v4.4.2 requires knplabs/github-api ^1.3 -> satisfiable by knplabs/github-api[1.7.1].
>       - Installation request for graham-campbell/github v4.4.2 -> satisfiable by graham-campbell/github[v4.4.2].
>
> To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in those .ini
>   files:
>       - C:\php\php.ini   You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.

Como Resolver?

Comment: Estão faltando as extensões ext-curl e ext-fileinfo no seu computador.

Comment: Exatamente, apenas ativei ela no php.ini porem está com outro nome: extension=php_curl.dll
extension=php_fileinfo.dll

Comment: Qual sistema operacional você está usando? Precisa habilitar o `Curl` para poder funcionar corretamente, conforme a mensagem de erro.

Answer (score -2):

execute:

```
composer update
```

Para atualizar o composer do projeto.